# Как подключится к X11 в Ubuntu

Tags: x11, ubuntu

не могу приконектится

```
root@~# export DISPLAY=172.49.1.100:0.0  root@~# xhost + 172.49.1.100  xhost:  unable to open display "172.49.11.108:0.0"
```

Нет контакта (подключаюсь Xmanager Enterprise 3 Xbrowser)

```
root@~# export DISPLAY=:0   root@~# xhost +   access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
```

Нет контакта.

Где еще смотреть, куда копать?

---

*IPшники из головы.

Comment: А что вы хотите, получить удаленны дисплей, так?

Comment: Уточню. Из под винды запускаю Xbrowser и пытаюсь получить удаленный доступ к компу под Ubuntu в граф. оболочку. Получаю чистый экранчег. Без попыток авторизации. Что-то я делаю не так, но где? Поиск по интернету ничего конкретного не дает.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -X user@ip-address
```

Набирайте нужную команду, например, firefox...